# How do I set up a namespace for an organization's users to share on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I create a namespace for an organization and have its multiple users belong to it?

I want each of my clients (which are organizations with multiple employees/users) to have their own namespace. I don't want to implement this by creating a bunch of different subdomains and mapping a namespace in that fashion.

I don't want each user to have a separate namespace, either--each user in an organization needs to work in the same namespace. This knocks out the following code recommended in Google's documentation:

```
def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():
    # assumes the user is logged in.
    return users.get_current_user().user_id()
```

When a client first signs up, I want their user model to belong to their company's namespace. When additional users are added by this first user, I want them to belong to that same company's namespace.

My problem is that if all the users belong to the company's namespace, none of them are available to my login function, which wouldn't know that a user's login info is hidden away in a specific namespace.

How should I re-approach this situation? I use Python, but can translate your Java answer if needed.

**EDIT:**

Instead, I've set up all model handling to have a Tenant model ancestor.

I set the key's identifier to a tenant_id that's generated with the sign-up user's email:

```
ndb.Key('Tenant', tenant_id)
```

and require all entity put() calls to have this key as a parent:

```
def tenant_key(tenant_id):
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a Tenant entity with tenant_id."""
    return ndb.Key('Tenant', tenant_id)

    ....

class Calendar(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()


    @classmethod
    def put_from_message(cls, calendar):
        # calendar represents a protoRPC message representing this entity's model

        # note: cls is the conventional "self" call for classes
        entity = cls(parent=tenant_key(calendar.tenant_id), title=calendar.title)
        entity.put()
```

Comment: What are you using for the user name. Are they logging in through google, or some openid provider ?  This may give you a solution.  For instance if all users for a specific company have an email address with the companies domain, then you could use the domain from the login as the namespace.  You would then only need to hold a single record for each user which does not belong to the namespace, where you look up the namespace based on the users domain.  Does that make sense ?

Comment: Since I'm using GAE Boilerplate (http://appengine.beecoss.com/), the login is custom: the user signs up with their email/pwd and is logged in in that manner. The issue with the email's domain is that, due to the industry I'm programming for, some signups will be with, for example, @yahoo.com.  If I were to throw a rough multi-tenancy capability together, I'd sign up a user and give them a tenant_id in their User model. I'd then assign that same tenant_id to any user created by him. I'm lost as to how this is done with the namespace manager, though

Comment: Have the record use the email as the key, and no namespace. A property is the namespace to use.  Set the name space once you have identified the user. Probably set the namespace in middelware. Can you give you an example later.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the coming example. With the namespace manager, it's set on every request, so the User information suddenly becomes unavailable when I switch the namespace according to a property from the User model.

Comment: Thats only if you want a different namespace for each user. You want a namespace shared for a set of users, read through the rest of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy and you will see different ways of doing it.

Comment: I read through that link many, many times before posting here. It suggests 1) the per User method, 2) Google Apps method (multiple subdomains), 3) manually changing it for every request made to the datastore; and then the python tic-tac-toe example covers using the Server name, the Google App subdomains method, and then using a cookie (which it declares in the example to be an insecure method). Which one of those is supposed to be what I'm looking for here? I don't see any of those methods working out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jay - I've been trying to figure out this exact problem. I don't think it's possible to globally set the namespace through appengine_config.py when you have independent users sometimes sharing a namespace. The three options offered in the documentation all presume that the user or some property of the users in a shared namespace is common, such as the domain. Using appengine_config.py requires that the shared property be known on sign-in.

These are the work arounds I've considered: require the users to login with the organization name as well as their username and use the organization name to set the namespace through app_config; force your users to have a google account; don't set the namespace globally- after the user logs in intialize a copy user account that is in the namespace and set the namespace in your handlers, or don't use namespaces.

The first is not great for user experience, but effective. The second is a disaster if you're making a business app. The third has a large potential for error depending on the complexity of your app. Since I have a small user base and I want to have a clean user experience, I decided not to use namespaces. But perhaps someone with more experience has better solutions than me.

Comment: Mike, thanks for sharing your experience. I got fed up and ended up not using namespaces, too. Especially after considering my use of Google Endpoints API. (edit: I posted what I do instead to my post's edit)

Comment: (can't edit comments, I guess) Please let me know if what I do in my edit is safe

Comment: I think it's secure: it's what I do anyway. I have a parent "Account", which is parent of all users and of the other Entities the users access. The "User" entity contains the users details, and is a child of Account, but is not a parent of the the other Entities. I think the only drawback to this method is that as your usage grows, searching and indexing is slower because they are not segregated by namespace.